# Fix the "color not declared" error in Dev C++ graphics

Tags: c++, graphics, graphics2d, dev-c++

I am still new to graphics in Dev C++ and I have encountered a problem while compiling a simple program for my school assignment.

I have installed all the libraries necessary for the Dev C++ graphics and added the 3 usual linkers (-lbgi -lgdi32 -luser32)->watched the tutorial for this part and the tests work.

I copied the same code that have worked on the school computer, but here it reports an error that the colors were not declared.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3kdK.jpg)

How do I fix this error? Please help. I couldn't find solution anywhere because the colors should work like that.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: According to https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setbkcolor.html , those colors are defined in graphics.h which you haven't included.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I cannot add graphics.h for some reason. For now, I resolve the problem by writing numbers...